# JSON - PHP foreach persistant error

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

Am quite frustrated with this and could use some savvy minds.
Am building a relatively simple API.
Using PHP have created the stdClass()'s and json_encode.
On the host server the data echos perfectly.
On the client side am getting a persistent foreach invalid argument error.

```
$thefez= new stdClass();
$thefez->muid=$id;
$thefez->bandname=$bandname;
$thefez->core=new stdClass();
   $thefez->core->joined=$since;
   $thefez->core->bandbio=$bio;
   $thefez->core->genre=$genre;
   $thefez->core->subgenre=$subgenre;

 echo json_encode($thefez);
```

The Result (Host)

```
{"muid":"IM5LGM02MFS8RJLKGY9W","bandname":"Marbles For Zen","core":  
{"joined":"Sun 01 March 2015","bandbio":"Zen And Marbles","genre":"Rhythm Blues",
"subgenre":"Dixie Rhythm"}}

{"muid":"IMA3YNBKZQDNR9RBCSRI","bandname":"Frankie Storm","core":  
{"joined":"Sat 21 February 2015","bandbio":"Just registered. Bio coming soon.","genre":"Popular","subgenre":""}}
```

ISSUE:
Using json_decode and foreach simply want to echo the items in the array.

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.mutrs.me/?artists'), TRUE);

foreach($result as $item){
$item->muid;
}
```

Host:

Checked json_last_error it returns 0
Checked json_last_error_msg it returns No Error

Client:

Checked json_last_error it returns **4**
Checked json_last_error_msg it returns **Syntax Error**

Answer (score 0):

jsondecode converts to array not an standard class object

try this
first `$result = json_decode($object , true);`

then for your item
    `$varname = $item['muid'];`

Test this compared to Your Code:

```
<?php
$data = '{"muid":"IM5LGM02MFS8RJLKGY9W","bandname":"Marbles For Zen","core":{"joined":"Sun 01 March 2015","bandbio":"Zen And Marbles","genre":"Rhythm Blues","subgenre":"Dixie Rhythm"}}';
var_dump(json_decode($data , true));
?>
```

Comment: `json_decode` returns an object.  Unless `true` is passed as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: well he can pass `true` as a parameter to get the json data

Comment: I did pass TRUE. and used the $item["muid"]. Still error.  When I dumped, am getting NULL. I just do not understand why on the client-side it errs but not on the host-side.

Comment: is both the json strings under a parent?

Comment: its because your getting 2 sets of json code from the request either split them or request a single json string, it returns null because theres 2 json strings there

Comment: John. The parameter "muid" and "bandname" are at top-level. The items under "core" are level two.

Comment: check the answer again ive edited it based on the request , the one above is requesting valid json, your json is invalid

Comment: I reduced the Host output to 1 and now am seeing it. But, shouldn't it return all the data, foreach group, like we do for any other API?

Comment: I run it through JSON lint, and yes, you're right there is a syntax error between the two outputted items. ...} { ...   How do I resolve this?

Comment: use substring and split it where the first json code closes